# JavaScript drag drawn canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I built a little webapp in which the user can draw lines on a canvas. Lets say I draw a circle, how can I make a function which selects each drawn object. Later on I want to resize(scale) the current clicked object. My Javascript function looks like this so far, but I do not know how to proceed.

So I need this steps

> - draw canvas with mouse (this works already)
> - click on each drawing
> - foreach drawing I want to for example create a slider which changes the size(scale)

```
var canvasTools = (function() {

    var CanvasEditor = function CanvasEditor(settings) {

        var color = settings.color || 'black',
            width = settings.width || 10;

        this.activeTool = null;
        this.canvas = settings.canvas;
        this.panel = settings.panel;
        this.panelInput = settings.panelInput;
        this.pencil = new Tool_pencil(this.canvas, color, width);

    };

    CanvasEditor.prototype = {

        'constructor': CanvasEditor,
        'clear': function clear() {
            this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            return this;
        },
        'init': function init() {
            this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function downHandler(event) {
                if (this.activeTool) {
                    this.activeTool.start(event);
                }
            }.bind(this), false);

            this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function downHandler(event) {
                if (this.activeTool && this.activeTool.active) {
                    this.activeTool.move(event);
                }
            }.bind(this), false);

            this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function downHandler(event) {
                if (this.activeTool) {
                    this.activeTool.end(event);
                }
            }.bind(this), false);

            return this;
        },
        'tool': function tool(toolName) {
            if (toolName && this[toolName]) {
                this.activeTool = this[toolName];
            }
            return this.activeTool;
        },
        'refresh': function refresh() {

        },
        'scale': function scale(panel, canvas, panelInput) {
            if (panel) {
                this.panel.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    var panelValue = this.value;
                    var newWidth  = canvas.width * panelValue;
                    var newHeight = canvas.height * panelValue;
                    panelInput.value = panelValue;
                    canvas.getContext('2d').scale(newWidth, newHeight);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("kein panel");
            }
        },
    };

    var CanvasTool = function CanvasTool(canvas) {
        if (!canvas) {
            console.log(this.name + ' - no canvas');
        }
        this.active = false;
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    };

    CanvasTool.prototype = {
        'constructor': CanvasTool,
        'coords': function coords(event) {
            return {
                'x': (event.layerX || event.offsetX),
                'y': (event.layerY || event.offsetY)
            };
        }
    };

    var Tool_pencil = function Tool_pencil(canvas, color, width) {
        CanvasTool.call(this, canvas);
        this._color = color;
        this._width = width;
    };

    Tool_pencil.prototype = Object.create(CanvasTool.prototype, {
        'constructor': {
            'value': Tool_pencil
        },
        'color': {
            'value': function color(newColor) {
                if (newColor) {
                    this._color = newColor;
                    return this;
                }
                return this._color;
            }
        },
        'end': {
            'value': function end(event) {
                this.move(event);
                this.active = false;
            }
        },
        'move': {
            'value': function move(event) {
                var location = this.coords(event);
                this.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                this.context.lineTo(location.x, location.y);
                this.context.stroke();
                //if(myCanvasTools.panelInput && myCanvasTools.panelInput.value && myCanvasTools.panelInput.value != 0) {
                myCanvasTools.scale(myCanvasTools.panel, myCanvasTools.canvas, myCanvasTools.panelInput);
                this.context.stroke();
                //}
            }
        },
        'start': {
            'value': function start(event) {
                var location = this.coords(event);
                this.context.beginPath();
                this.context.strokeStyle = this.color();
                this.context.lineWidth = this.width();
                this.context.moveTo(location.x, location.y);
                this.active = true;
            }
        },
        'width': {
            'value': function width(newWidth) {
                if (newWidth) {
                    this._width = newWidth;
                    return this;
                }
                return this._width;
            }
        }
    });

    return function canvasToolsFactory(settings) {
        return new CanvasEditor(settings);
    };
}());

// Canvas Modul Initialiseren
var myCanvasTools = canvasTools({
    'canvas': document.querySelector('#imageView'),
    'panel': document.querySelector('#canvasSliderPanel'),
    'panelInput': document.querySelector('#canvasDepthValue'),
    'color': 'black',
    'width': 5
});

myCanvasTools.init();
```

**Edit**
A few people suggested me to use a library like fabric.js, but is there a way to combine those so to say? Currently I do not want to recode everything, but worst case scenario I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below mentioned solution. This is running code which you want, This is created for demo purpose only. Please modify as per your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper', {
        isDrawingMode: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    });
    var isDown;

    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    var drawingColorEl = $('#drawing-color');
    var drawingLineWidthEl = $('#drawing-line-width');

    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = drawingColorEl.val();
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = drawingLineWidthEl.val();

    drawingColorEl.change(function() {
        isDown = true;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = this.value;
    });

    drawingLineWidthEl.change(function() {
        isDown = true;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = drawingLineWidthEl.val();
    });



    $('#selectMode').click(function() {
        var objs = [];
        objs = canvas.getObjects();

        var alltogetherObj = new fabric.Group(objs, {
        });
        canvas._activeObject = null;
        if (objs.length != 0) {
            canvas.setActiveGroup(alltogetherObj.setCoords()).renderAll();
        }
        isDown = false;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

    });

    $('#drawMode').click(function() {
        isDown = true;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        canvas.discardActiveObject();
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.min.js"></script>

<select id="drawing-color">
    <option value="#ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="#000000">Black</option>
</select>

<select id="drawing-line-width">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="selectMode" value="Select Mode" />
<input type="button" id="drawMode" value="Draw Mode"/>
<canvas id="paper" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Do you have an example on which someone can draw and select that area + size function?

Comment: So you mean to say create function for draw rectangle..? like this you are asking

Comment: My current script lets one draw lines, circle etc using the mouse, I want to select the drawing I made with the mouse. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @utdev : You want to select all that specific objects which are created with mouse only

Comment: I have updated answer, But with that you can select all object with mouse. Can you please check my example.

Comment: You probably did not understand me correctly. I draw a circle with the canvas and I want to select that drawn circle. I move the mouse around the canvas to draw that circle for example

Comment: How would you change it to make a basic draw, writing a name or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146621/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-utdev).

Comment: Please check my updated code, Hope this is what you want. Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Thanks this will help me <8

Comment: @utdev : Glad to help you out from this hurdle.

Comment: Currently I am struggling to integrate this nativ javascript way, the way above (posted code), would you mind helping me to integrate it?

Comment: Definitely, we are here to help you friend, let me know how can I help you

Comment: Currently I built my whole canvas functions using only javascript no libraries nor jquery, what would be the best way to implement the functionality you posted

Comment: The best way you can do is1. Use Google Jquery library and Febric.js library. Because I have doe it before and also done in jQuery only.

Comment: Could you help me combine those two?

Comment: Sure, Lets do it in chat  `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146621/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-utdev`

Comment: Hi thanks again so I decided to rebuilt my entire javascript using the fabric library, I got one last question if you choose for example the width of 10 and the color black and draw something it somehow changes the shapes or the drawing how to I prevent this

Comment: Yes I have seen this when I writing code for your application, Actually we have to use some specific version of jQuery and Fabric JS. I will let you tomorrow with exact versions of both the files.

Comment: @utdev, If you are doing it with fabricjs than let me know, I can help you with any of your requirement or issue.

Comment: I am using fabric js now which version of bootstrap and fabric js do I need

Comment: Fabricjs version : `version: "1.6.3"`, jQuery Version : `jQuery v2.2.2`, Try with this, I have used this and it working perfect for me.

Comment: I get a strange behavoiur, my canvas is 1400x800 large and if I draw a few things and try to select each the selectmode selects everything and drags everything, any idea why?

Comment: Please check this are the tools I have done so far with fabric js http://i.stack.imgur.com/R5p3X.png , On top right you can see Icons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple task, and from my opinion, you should use something like pixie.js library, please look into this example -

http://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/demos/dragging.js

But, if you are really want to implement it by self, it will be a true challenge. I can suggest to check my code here - http://kill-them.com/assets/js/applications/MapEditor.js?v=7

To check how it work you can go to http://kill-them.com/, press `short session` and then go to `map editor` in top menu. There you will be able to see map editor, where you will be able to put wall. There there will be controls such as resize and rotate. But really, if I will start same project from scratch one more time, I will use libraries.